# How to redirect guest to login page using a beforeRequest in Yii 2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2-advanced-app

I have a problem. I use a `RequestBehavior.php` (a modified AccessBehavior.php created by Artem Voitko) created in `common\components`, but I don't know how to redirect guests to `frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Flogin`.

This is the code for `RequestBehavior.php`:

```
<?php
/*
 * In configuration file
 * ...
 * 'as AccessBehavior' => [
 *    'class' => '\app\components\AccessBehavior'
 * ]
 * ...
 * (c) Artem Voitko <r3verser@gmail.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */
namespace common\components;
use yii\base\Behavior;
use yii\console\Controller;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\web\Application;
/**
 * Redirects all users to login page if not logged in
 *
 * Class AccessBehavior
 * @package app\components
 * @author  Artem Voitko <r3verser@gmail.com>
 */
class RequestBehavior extends Behavior
{
    /**
     * Subscribe for events
     * @return array
     */
    public function events()
    {
        return [
            Application::EVENT_BEFORE_REQUEST => 'beforeRequest'
        ];
    }
    /**
     * On event callback
     */
    public function beforeRequest()
    {
        if (\Yii::$app->getUser()->isGuest &&
            \Yii::$app->getRequest()->url !== Url::to(\Yii::$app->getUser()->loginUrl)
        ) {
            \Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(\Yii::$app->getUser()->loginUrl);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And using it, shows this error:

```
Unable to resolve the relative route: site/login. No active controller is available.
```

I tried using beforeAccess, but I need to redirect before a request. I need help, please.

Comment: Why don't you use AccessControl? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

Comment: I tried using AccessControl, but I got exceptions when I try to search a model using session data even before using the beforeAction by AccessControl, like this error:

`Trying to get property of non-object`
(...) `->andFilterWhere(['like', 'rutProfesor', Yii::$app->user->identity->rutProfesor]);`